# DateTime::createFromFormat() returns wrong date

Tags: php, date, parsing, datetime, php-7

I'm using `(\DateTime::createFromFormat()` to parse a date.

**In**
`"25/03/2017 10:43"`

**Out**
`"2020-07-25 10:00:00.000000"`

**Code**

`dd(\DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:m", Request::get('start')));`

The date is formed as follows: "dd/mm/yyyy". As you can see it's 3 years, 4 months, and 43 minutes off. The days and hours work fine though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your date format to

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', '25/03/2017 10:43')
```

Note the `i`: it means minutes. `m` means months. See [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Comment: Ah, right. Can't believe I missed something as simple as that :O

Answer (score 1):

The format character for minutes is `i` and not `m`.

```
dd(\DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i", Request::get('start')));
```

Comment: Yeah, *facepalm* Thanks!